# Type JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley, android-json

When I call my service web i have this exception: `org.json.JSONException:Value[{}]` of type `org.json.JSONArray` cannot be converted to `JSONObject`

```js
private void jsonParse(){
        String url="http://192.168.56.1:8095/rest/workouts/all";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("");

                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject w = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String title = w.getString("title");
                                String goal = w.getString("goal");

                                txtv.append(title + ", " + goal +"\n\n");
                            }
                        ...
```

**By the way this is the `JSON` Format**

```
[{"id":"1","title":"title","goal":"goal","exercice":"Exercice 
1","difficulty":"Beginner","duration":"3","image":"..","description":"..."},]
```

Comment: Change JSONObject to JSONArray in the Response Listener

Comment: You have to use `JsonArrayRequest` instead of `JsonObjectRequest `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution that i found, thanks for all guys ♥ ..

```js
    private void jsonParse(){
        String url="http://192.168.56.1:8095/rest/workouts/all";
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                        try {
                            
                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {


                                JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                String title = jsonobject.getString("title");
                                String goal = jsonobject.getString("goal");

                                txtv.append(title + ", " + goal +"\n\n");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });
        mQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json response is actually a JsonArray, so you need to change your code to:

```
private void jsonParse(){
    String url="http://192.168.56.1:8095/rest/workouts/all";
    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray >() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    try {


                        for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject w = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            String title = w.getString("title");
                            String goal = w.getString("goal");

                            txtv.append(title + ", " + goal +"\n\n");
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one**

```
try{

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response.string());
        for (int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

            String Title=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("title");
            String Goal=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("goal");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                    Request.Method.GET,
                    url,
                    null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

                            for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject w = response.getJSONObject(i);

                            String title = w.getString("title");
                            String goal = w.getString("goal");

                            txtv.append(title + ", " + goal +"\n\n");
                             }

                            }catch (JSONException e){
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                            // Do something when error occurred

                        }
                    }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Though the answers can handle your case, but looking at your JSON, it's clearly an array not an object, the correct format of your JSON could be something like this:

```
{"id":"1","title":"title","goal":"goal","exercice":"Exercice1","difficulty":"Beginner","duration":"3","image":"..","description":"..."}
```

Which have no "[", "]" and ",". So here's my solution, if it's expected to receive just a single Object all the time, you should change your API, sending you just an object as I mentioned above, otherwise, that "," at the end is incorrect for an array having just one single item, and anyhow, you have to change your model to except an array [which you can declare it as a list like: `List<Model> myModelList`] so that the parser will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

try this ... It should be

```
JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
```

and then

```
for(int i=0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
   JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

   //your code
}
```